# not able to launch mlflow ui

Tags: python, mlflow

I get the following error when running mlflow ui:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    run()  # pragma nocover
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\runner.py", line 298, in run
    _serve(app, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\__init__.py", line 13, in serve
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\server.py", line 78, in create_server
    last_serv = TcpWSGIServer(
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\server.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.bind_server_socket()
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\server.py", line 361, in bind_server_socket
    self.bind(sockaddr)
  File "C:\Users\user\ML\lib\site-packages\waitress\wasyncore.py", line 396, in bind
    return self.socket.bind(addr)
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions    
Running the mlflow server failed. Please see the logs above for details.
```

Python 3.10
mlflow 2.9.2
IDE VSCode

I don't know if this is related but I started getting this error after upgrading VSCode.

I tried mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0, the error disappears but I get localhost page not found in the browser (tried with localhost:5000, 0.0.0.0:5000, 127.0.0.1:5000).

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the MLflow UI error:

1. Address Permission Issues:

Run as Administrator: Right-click on your terminal or command prompt and select "Run as administrator" to grant necessary permissions.
Check Firewall: Ensure your firewall isn't blocking MLflow's port (5000 by default). If necessary, create an exception for it.
Close Conflicting Applications: Close any other programs that might be using the same port, such as other web servers or development tools.
2. Resolve Host Binding Issues:

Specify Host Address: If mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0 results in a "localhost page not found" error, try using --host 127.0.0.1 instead.
Check Network Settings: Verify that your network settings are correct, and you're not using a VPN or proxy that might interfere with local connections.
3. Inspect MLflow Logs:

Enable Verbose Logging: Run mlflow ui --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db --host 127.0.0.1 --verbose to get more detailed logs.
Inspect for Clues: Examine the logs for additional error messages or hints about the root cause.
4. Consider Environment-Specific Issues:

Virtual Environments: If you're using a virtual environment, ensure MLflow is installed within it and activated correctly.
VS Code Permissions: Double-check that VS Code has the necessary permissions to access network resources.
5. Additional Troubleshooting:

Upgrade/Downgrade MLflow: Consider upgrading or downgrading MLflow to a different version to see if it resolves compatibility issues.
Reinstall MLflow: Completely reinstall MLflow to address potential installation corruption.
Check for Conflicting Python Versions: Ensure you're using the correct Python environment and version where MLflow is installed.
Seek Community Support: If the issue persists, search for similar problems and solutions in MLflow's community forums or GitHub repository.
If none of these steps resolve the issue, provide more details about your environment (OS, Python version, MLflow version, specific VS Code configuration) for further assistance.